# How can i split string to list using scala

Tags: scala

i has string `str = "one,two,(three,four), five"`

I want to split this string into list, like this:
`List[String] = ("one", "two", "(three, four)", "five")`?

i have no idea for this.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try matching on the pattern `\(.*?\)|[^, ]+`:

```scala
val str = "one,two,(three,four), five"
val re = """\(.*?\)|[^, ]+""".r
for(m <- re.findAllIn(str)) println(m)
```

This prints:

```
one
two
(three,four)
five
```

This regex pattern eagerly first tries to find a `(...)` term.  That failing, it matches any content other than comma or space, to consume one CSV term at a time.  This trick avoids the problem of matching across commas inside `(...)`.

Comment: woh, i solve my problem with this. I appreciate you for answer. Thanks so much